# Android: How to draw 8 equal rectangles to fit screen width with XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-drawable

I'm new to JAVA and Android development.

Basically I would like to draw 8 equal rectangles (keyboard keys) to fit on 100% width.

As far as I know linearlayout doesn't support drawables, so sadly that piece of code doesn't work for me:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/keyboardKey1"
        android:background="@drawable/keyboard_key_white"
        android:weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/keyboardKeyC"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/keyboardKeyA" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/keyboardKey2"
        android:background="@drawable/keyboard_key_white"
        android:weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/keyboardKeyC"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/keyboardKeyA" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here are the contents of **keyboard_key_while.xml** as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#fff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000" />
</shape>
```

As far as I know, I also can't do the the other way round and use linearlayout inside of the drawable XML. Can you give me suggestions of how to achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: "As far as I know linearlayout doesn't support drawables"... If with support drawables you mean the ability to set a background, you are wrong. A viewgroup is also a view, so you can of course set drawables as background.

Comment: Use `PercentLinearLayout`, add 6 other layouts with 16% height. Adjust percentage width to the other 6 so you can add the views.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure my JAVA/Android knowledge level is enough to fully understand it though. I meant that it's not working as expected in the example I provided - the android:weight attribute doesn't work at all. Do you mean that I need to use another element instead of <view> and assign android:background to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a `LinearLayout` set to horizontal orientation and have each view inside that set an equal `layout_weight` and zero `layout_width`. You were almost there but you have to use `layout_weight` instead of `weight`.

This shows two keys taking up the width of the screen. If you put 8 views in there it scales accordingly.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/keyboardKey1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/keyboard_key_white" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/keyboardKey2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/keyboard_key_white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Two more things**

in your example you are using `RelativeLayout` layout parameters in the keyboard views (`layout_alignTop` and `layout_toRightOf`). However the keyboard views are being hosted by a `LinearLayout` and are therefore ignored so they can be left out.

Another way to do this is to use the `GridLayout` where you can specify how many columns and rows you want. Inside the GridLayout you specify for each child view in which column and row you want it to appear with `layout_column` and `layout_row`.

Read up on Layouts on the [Android Developer API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

Answer (score 1):

I did this before.  Let me check my code to see if I still have it.

I found it. The layout I created is for a calculator.  I wanted the buttons to scale according to screen size.

[image]

I used a TextView with solid white background for the buttons.  I'm sure you could use a drawable for a background as well.  Anyway, have a look at the way I did the LinearLayouts.

### The Code

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    >

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/name"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="3"
      android:background="#ffffff"
      android:text="Food"
      android:gravity="center|right"
      android:paddingRight="0dp"
      android:singleLine="true" 
      android:textSize="27sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:onClick="onViewClick"  
      />

    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/more"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@drawable/layer_list_arrow_dn"  
      android:gravity="center"
      android:singleLine="true"    
      android:onClick="onViewClick"  
      />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    >

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/amount"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="3"
      android:background="#ffffff"
      android:text="0.00"
      android:gravity="center|right"
      android:paddingRight="0dp"
      android:singleLine="true"    
      android:textSize="27sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"  
      android:onClick="onViewClick"  
      />

    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/clear"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@drawable/layer_list_clear"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:singleLine="true"    
      android:onClick="onViewClick"  
      />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="#00fcb514"
    >

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:background="#00333333"
      >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_holo_blue_bright"
        android:text="7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b02"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:background="#00666666"
      >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:background="#00999999"
      >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b20"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b21"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b22"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b23"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="."
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
      android:background="#00cccccc"
      >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b30"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/layer_list_arrow_up"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b31"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/layer_list_arrow_dn"  
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:onClick="onViewClick"  
        />

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but in my case I'm using custom Views, just like in the snippet I posted.

Comment: TextView inherits from View so it's the same thing.  Just use the same properties I used in the layout.  One thing I noticed is that you used 0dip and I used 0dp.  You should also pay attention to the weights.  Everything you need is there.